# Changing the Text of a Grouped TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

The animation below depicts the manual change of a text inside a `TextBox` AFTER the `TextBox` has been grouped with another shape ( an `msoShapeOval` ).

[image]

Q: How to perform the same task in VBA ?

I tried the following code - it groups the two shapes correctly but after that it fails at the last line:

```
Sub ChangeTextAfterGrouping()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim tb As Shape
    Dim ShpArray() As Variant

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 200, 40, 120, 70)
    Set tb = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextBox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 235, 65, 50, 20)
    
    tb.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "ABC"    'Success
    
    ReDim ShpArray(1 To 2)
    ShpArray(1) = shp.Name
    ShpArray(2) = tb.Name
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(ShpArray).Group
    
    tb.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "XYZ"    'Error        
End Sub
```

Other people are reporting the same problem. See:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/388251-editing-text-in-text-box-grouped-within-a-trapezoid.html

Comment: When I run your code, it runs successfully, without any errors.

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: 3 Questions: Which version of MS-Excel did you try it on? Do you get the text "XYZ" inside the `TextBox` after the VBA code finishes?  Is the `TextBox` grouped with the `Oval` after it finishes ?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft 365.  And yes, the text "XYZ" replaced the text "ABC".

Answer (score 0):

In my Office 2007 your code works pretty well with no error.

Comment: 2 Questions: Do you get the text "XYZ" inside the `TextBox` after the VBA code finishes?  Is the `TextBox` grouped with the `Oval` after it finishes ?

Comment: My answers: yes and yes

Comment: OK, I will accept you answer but please wait till we get some data how other versions of MS-Excel behave and add this data to your answer for posterity.  BTW: I run this test on MS-Excel 2003.